# google.Maps.Circle repeats in every clone part of google map on small zoom option

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know the way to prevent the repeating property of circle in every clone part of google map.

In google.Maps API I found the similar option of marker it's: optimized property set to false. 
The parts of my code:

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.2169, -97.1336),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        }
    });
        this.circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.2169, -97.1336),
            radius: 1609344,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            strokeColor: "#e64646",
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
            visible: false,
            map: this.map
        });
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to control that. Markers are cloned only when they are not draggable, but that doesn't seem to be the case with circles.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried change the property draggable from true to false in my circle, but unfortunately it didn't help me.

Comment: Maybe you could limit the minimum zoom level to prevent multiple maps from being displayed?

Comment: Yes, that's great idea, I thought about it, but in my application all zoom levels of the map should be available.